# How to mock IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper

This is the approach I am following for develop unit tests.

My project under test using Entity Framework, so
I am Mocking Entity frame work in my tests, I am creating in memory data(for tables), in test project.

My project using Mapper from vw_employees to User in the following way.

```
configuration.CreateMap<vw_employees, User>().ForMember(m => m.Id, opt =>opt.MapFrom(u => u.ID)).ForMember(m => m.DisplayName, opt =>opt.MapFrom(u => u.FullName));
```

so I want to mock the above configuration.CreateMap, so that I will get User object from the mocking.

```
public class User : IHaveCustomMappings
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string UserDomain { get; set; }
    public long? bId { get; set; }

    public void CreateMappings(IMapperConfiguration configuration)
    {
        try
        {
            configuration.CreateMap<vw_employees, User>().ForMember(m => m.Id, opt =>opt.MapFrom(u => u.ID)).ForMember(m => m.DisplayName, opt =>opt.MapFrom(u => u.FullName));
        }
        catch (AutoMapperConfigurationException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

In unit tests, I am trying to Mock the mapper in following way, but its not working.

```
var mappingservice = new Mock<IMapperConfiguration>();
var im = new User { Id = "1234", DisplayName = "abc", Role =     null,UserDomain= "xyz", bid = null };
mappingservice.Setup(m => m.CreateMap<vw_employees, ApplicationUser>());
```

Please help me, how to resolve the following dependency from the above class while testing.

```
 public void CreateMappings(IMapperConfiguration configuration)
    {
        try
        {
            configuration.CreateMap<vw_employees, User>().ForMember(m => m.Id, opt =>opt.MapFrom(u => u.ID)).ForMember(m => m.DisplayName, opt =>opt.MapFrom(u => u.FullName));
        }
        catch (AutoMapperConfigurationException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to test your mappings, or test that automapper works?  I don't think you need to mock anything !

Comment: @Neil nope I think that he wants to mock the `configuration` instance in his some sort of controller or service unit tests.

Comment: @kayess that sounds like he wants to test AutoMapper? I suggest this is not something he needs to test !

Comment: @Neil not at all. Checking his posted code, his class-under-test is `User` which has the `configuration` variable instance and I think that is what he wants to be mocked out in his unit test, but let OP kick in and make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mock IMappingExpression. Actually, do not mock *anything* in AutoMapper. Just use it directly. Mocking anything in AutoMapper does not add any value, and I can't imagine why you'd want to mock *configuration*.

Comment: For more information, I have edited my above question , please look into it and help me!

Comment: My answer is still the same - you don't want to mock AutoMapper, ever really. Above, just pass in an actual instance of a MappingConfiguration into your call, not a faked/mocked out version.